# build multiple json hash in same json in oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql

below two queries are returning a separate JSON when I merge the data. it's showing in invalid data.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Agriculture_Expenses' value
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Acreage12' value acreage,
                                             'Farmer_projected' value
                                             sellingprice,
                                             'Projected_Expense' value attr1,
                                             'Pattern1' value crop
                                             
                                             )
                                 --  JSON_OBJECT('ITEM' VALUE .50)
                                 ))
  INTO AFL_JSON

  FROM AGRI_INCOME
 WHERE ATTR2 = 'AGRICULTURE_INCOME';

SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Cash_Flow_Form' value
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Agri_Coapp1' value rec.Coapp1,
                                             'Agri_Coapp2' value rec.Coapp2,
                                             'Agri_Coapp3' value rec.Coapp3,
                                             'Lease_Land' value
                                             rec.lease_land,
                                             'Total_Land' value '',
                                             'Land_under_cultivation1' value
                                             rec.Land_under_cultivation,
                                             'App_agr_lan' value
                                             rec.Land_Holding)
                                 
                                 ))
  INTO AFL_JSON
  FROM dual;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(AFL_JSON_DATA);
```

below two query is returning a data as below format extra { is coming when i merge two json object how can i get the data in below format.

```json
{
  "Cash_Flow_Form": [
    {
      "Agri_Coapp1": "1",
      "Agri_Coapp2": "2",
      "Agri_Coapp3": null,
      "Lease_Land": "2",
      "Total_Land": null,
      "Land_under_cultivation1": "4",
      "App_agr_lan": "5"
    }
  ],
  "Agriculture_Expenses": [
    {
      "Acreage12": "2",
      "Farmer_projected": "2500",
      "Projected_Expense": "81400",
      "Pattern1": "Khariff"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON_MERGEPATCH()` function within a `SELECT` statement `CROSS JOIN`ing those `JSON_OBJECT`s

```
WITH AGRI_INCOME_JS AS
(
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'Agriculture_Expenses' value
                    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT ('Acreage12'         value accreage,
                                               'Farmer_projected'  value sellingprice,
                                               'Projected_Expense' value attr1,
                                               'Pattern1'          value crop
                                               )
                                  )
                    ) AS JS2
  FROM AGRI_INCOME
 WHERE ATTR2 = 'AGRICULTURE_INCOME'
), CASH_FLOW_JS AS
(
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Cash_Flow_Form' value
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Agri_Coapp1' value coapp1,
                                             'Agri_Coapp2' value coapp2,
                                             'Agri_Coapp3' value coapp3,
                                             'Lease_Land' value  lease_land,
                                             'Total_Land' value  Total_Land,
                                             'Land_under_cultivation1' value Land_under_cultivation,
                                             'App_agr_lan' value Land_Holding
                                             )
                                 )            
                                 
                  ) AS JS1
  FROM CASH_FLOW
)
SELECT JSON_MERGEPATCH(JS1,JS2) AS "Result JSON"
  FROM CASH_FLOW_JS
 CROSS JOIN AGRI_INCOME_JS
```

The above query works for 18+, If your DB version is 12c, then use :

```
WITH AGRI_INCOME_JS AS
(
SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'Agriculture_Expenses' value
                    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT ('Acreage12'         value accreage,
                                               'Farmer_projected'  value sellingprice,
                                               'Projected_Expense' value attr1,
                                               'Pattern1'          value crop
                                               )
                                  )
                    ) AS JS2
  FROM AGRI_INCOME
 WHERE ATTR2 = 'AGRICULTURE_INCOME'
), CASH_FLOW_JS AS
(
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('Cash_Flow_Form' value
                   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Agri_Coapp1' value coapp1,
                                             'Agri_Coapp2' value coapp2,
                                             'Agri_Coapp3' value coapp3,
                                             'Lease_Land' value  lease_land,
                                             'Total_Land' value  Total_Land,
                                             'Land_under_cultivation1' value Land_under_cultivation,
                                             'App_agr_lan' value Land_Holding
                                             )
                                 )            
                                 
                  ) AS JS1
  FROM CASH_FLOW
), JS(JS) AS
( SELECT JS1 FROM CASH_FLOW_JS
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT JS2 FROM AGRI_INCOME_JS)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_ARRAYAGG(JS),'\'),'["'),'"]'),'}","{',',') 
    AS "Result JSON"
  FROM JS
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=67e79a176b16091e68617b2113725cdd)</kbd>